# Why I can't listen 127.0.0.1:port by socket

Tags: java, macos, sockets

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

no program using the port

```java
Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 9876);
```

```java
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
```

Comment: You are not listening.  You are connecting.  That means that there must be another program that is listening.  The "connection refused" exceptions means that is not so.

Comment: But I already closed my firewall. And how can the socket succseefully connect the port on my laptop?

Comment: oh! I got it! Thank you !

Comment: @Giotto you (should) not have to make any changes to your firewall to connect to some port on localhost

Answer (score 1):

You create client socket. So some server should listen 9876 port otherwise you will get `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)`. If you want to listen 9876 use:

**Server:**

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9876);
Socket socket = server.accept(); // accept() waiting for client connection
//read from socket on server
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
System.out.println("Message from client " + in.readLine());
```

After that you can create a client:

**Cient:**

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 9876);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
out.write("Hello! " + "\n"); // send to server
out.flush();
```